# How to add Maven Home (M2_HOME) in PATH in Alpine Linux based docker container

Tags: linux, docker, maven, alpine-linux, maven-invoker-plugin

I need to use Maven-invoker in my app. I run my app in an Alpine-based docker container. So, I put into Dockerfile commands to install Maven and add the Maven Home directory to the PATH environment variable.

When the container is up I can go inside and see, that Maven Home is not in the PATH.
Once I run "source /etc/profile.d/maven.sh" manually in container I can see the maven home in the PATH, but it disappears when I open a new terminal.

My maven.sh contains following:
`export PATH=/usr/share/java/maven-3/bin:$PATH`

Also I tried this:

```
export M2_HOME=/usr/share/java/maven-3
export MAVEN_HOME=/usr/share/java/maven-3
export PATH=${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```

My Dockerfile contains:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache maven
COPY maven.sh /etc/profile.d
RUN chmod +x /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
RUN source /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
```

I will be very grateful for help in solving this problem.

Comment: What's your entrypoint?

Comment: Why do oyu need M2_HOME, MAVEN_HOME? Just use `export PATH=/usr/shared/java/maven-3/bin:${PATH}`...

Comment: Can you explain why: `Maven-invoker `?

Comment: @AlexeyR., the entrypoint is `["./run.sh"]`; run.sh = `#!/bin/sh
exec java ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar /app.jar ${@}`

Comment: @khmarbaise, I tried this as well. PATH holds added value only in a current terminal session.

Comment: @khmarbaise, I want to use a maven plugin in runtime. So I need to have Maven installed in my docker container. It works on my local computer

Comment: which plugins? And why inside the container?

Comment: @khmarbaise, the purpose is to convert swagger documentation into PDF make it downloadable from a special web page. I use Swagger2MarkupConverter to convert documentation into askiidocs, and then I use asciidoctor-maven-plugin and asciidoctorj-pdf to convert that askiidocs to PDF. It works well during maven build circle. So , the idea is to install maven into a docker container and use maven-invoker to generate pdf documentation in runtime.

Comment: @khmarbaise, I solved this problem by adding ENV PATH=/usr/share/java/maven-3/bin:$PATH into Dockerfile. Now the maven.home is in PATH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding
`ENV PATH=/usr/share/java/maven-3/bin:$PATH`
into Dockerfile. Now the maven.home is in PATH.